# Masked blurring

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I have some image I and some heatmap H. I want to apply blurring to the image according to the heatmap. The larger the value H(i,j) the stronger should be the blur in the region of I(i,j).

For example, here I do that by discretizing the heatmap into 10 bins and prepare 10 images with the range of blur: I0 - no blur, I9 - image with the strongest blur. Then I construct the resulting image as R(i, j) = IN(i, j), where N is determined by the bin where H(i,j) falls.
[image]

Is there a way to do something similar, without the discretization? Any idea of how to **apply blur according to the heatmap** is appreciated.